# warning C4127: conditional expression is constant in cl command

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, if-statement, c4127

```
#define Val_MAX 0
int main() {
   if(Val_MAX)
      printf("The value is %d",VALUE_MAX);
   return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile  the above program `if(VALUE_MAX)` is showing a warning

> conditional expression is constant.

How to solve the above warning?

Comment: Select the `if(Val_MAX)` and `printf` lines. Now hit the delete key to remove them, keeping only `return 0;` that's all this will ever do anyway.

Comment: And if using C++, or C99 or higher, you can also leave out the `return 0;`.

Comment: @MohitJain Wow, never knew a tag exists for `c4127` itself. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I create it for my question (shy)

Comment: @MohitJain Well, a question of that stature deserves it's own tag. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `Val_MAX` being a `#define`d value to `0`

```
if(Val_MAX)
```

is actually (you can check after preprocessing with `gcc -E`)

```
if(0)
```

which is not of any worth. The Following `printf()` will never execute.

FWIW, a selection statement like `if` needs an expression, for which the value evaluation will be *expectedly* be done at runtime. For a fixed value, a selection statement makes no sense. It's most likely going to end up being an "Always TRUE" or "Always FALSE" case.

**One Possible solution:** *[With some actual usage of selection statement]*

Make the `Val_MAX` a variable, ask for user input for the value, then use it. A pseudo-code will look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
   int Val_MAX = 0;

   printf("Enter the value of Val_MAX\n");
   scanf("%d", &Val_MAX);

   if(Val_MAX)
      printf("The value is %d",VALUE_MAX);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2931858 It is not about the compiler, it's about the usage of `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `preprocessor directive` will replace `VAL_MAX` with `0` it becomes

```
if(0)
```

So anyways it will be false always and your `printf` won't execute and so `if` condition is of no use